# What is the execution context for an asynchronous method?

Tags: apex, asynchronous, context

Is it always system context, or it depends on where the method is called?

Comment: It runs in the context of user who initiated that async method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where it's called from, but it *does* matter if you specify "with sharing." If you specify "with sharing," then sharing is enforced. If you do not specify a sharing mode, or you specify "without sharing," it runs in system context.

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood. The sharing setting matters on where it is called, or on the class where the method is?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira The Scheduled class itself, not wherever it's called from.